# Why do i not have access to Content folder in MVC3 app under IIS7.5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a fresh File -> New Project MVC3 application. When i Publish it and run it in IIS7.5 everything in the Contents folder seems to be inaccessible. Every other folder seems to work fine.

```
<img src="@Url.Content("/Content/1.png")"/>
<img src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/1.png")"/>
```

With this code Sample the top image is missing but the bottom one displays fine.

I have tried it in IIS express and everything works fine. Everything works fine when i start debugging the Site in IIS from Visual Studio.
It doesn´t seem to be an file access problem since the whole app folder has permissions for the IIS app pool and accessing content in the Scripts folder works.
Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the '~' (the app root path)

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/1.png")"/>
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/1.png")"/>
```

Comment: you are right, i should have added that. saddly it doesnt solve the problem:(

Comment: Are you sure the 1.png file is in ~Content? In fact, it's curious that it's in Scripts where only js files should be.

Comment: i threw it in there just to see if it would be found in a different dir.